# Non-type template parameter for polymorphic lambda?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, variadic-templates, index-sequence

Is it possible to write something like this?

```
[](std::index_sequence<std::size_t ...I> s) {

};
```

Or this?

```
[]<std::size_t ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...> s) { 

}
```

How is the syntax for this in C++14 or C++17? Or is it not possible at all? Basically, I just want to have the `I` as a template parameter pack, and the lambda just serves as a way to do that. Alternatively, is there a syntax to achieve the following?

```
std::index_sequence<std::size_t ...I> x = std::make_index_sequence<10>{};

// I now is a local template parameter pack
```

Comment: Not quite what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/572/lambdas/14626/using-lambdas-for-inline-parameter-pack-unpacking#t=201607280832233700555 but can solve a subset of problems you are facing.  In general, the answer is no, but if you can provide a specific probkem there are slick solutions sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

GCC provides the latter syntax [as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html), but it's not standard:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void foo(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t) {
    auto l = [&t]<std::size_t ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...> s) { 
        std::initializer_list<int>{ (std::cout << std::get<I>(t), 0)... };
    };

    l(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28c21d9ce2c01689)</kbd>

Comment: Is this standard with C++20?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly the same, but maybe you can push the sequence with an helper function as it follows:

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

auto lambda = [](auto... I){
    int arr[] = { (std::cout << I << std::endl, 0)... };
    (void)arr;
};

template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto f(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return lambda(I...);
}

int main() {
    f(std::make_index_sequence<3>());
}
```